# How to replaces commas in list of names separated by commas

Tags: python, regex, csv

In Python, I have a string of names separated by commas and I am trying to add double square brackets around the names.

Here is the format of the original string.
`1. John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, etc.<br>`

What I want to end up with is:
`1. [[John Smith1]], [[John Smith2]], [[John Smith3]], [[etc.]]<br>`

I tried using this regex:
`(.+?)(?:, |(<br>)$)`

with this replacement:
`[[\1]], \2`

But it is giving this result:
`[[1. John Smith1]], [[John Smith2]], [[John Smith3]], [[etc.,]]<br>`

1. How do I move the initial "\d.\s" outside the first name capture?
2. How do I prevent the final comma after the last name (in this case, etc. instead of etc.,)?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
My apologies for not being more specific. When I stated I wanted to match this, I should have said match "only" this pattern.

When I used this regex: `(?<=\.\s|,\s)([^,\r\n]+)\s*(?=<br>|,)` and this replacement `[[\1]]`it did two unexpected things.
1. Although it works in regex101.com, when I look at the output in Notepad++, all the names are changed to SOH, and in Notepad they become non-printing characters.
2. It is too aggressive, so it changed every instance of multiple items separated by commas.
So the output from this:
`1. John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, John Smith4<br>`
`This is the reason why John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, and John Smith4 did what they did.<br>`

looks like this in Notepad++:

`1. [[SOH]], [[SOH]], [[SOH]], [[SOH]]<br>`
`This is the reason why John Smith1, [[SOH]], [[SOH]], and John Smith4 did what they did.<br>`

I'll give the other suggestions a try to see if any work.

Thanks again.

**Latest Update**
I solved the non-printing issue. I forgot to escape the substitution string in the regex with "r". Now, if I can get the regex to stop at the first `<br>`, I should get what I need. Still searching...

One other thing: there will be more numbered lines with comma-separated names and descriptions with line breaks in the string. So

```
1. FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 LastName2, FirstName3 LastName3<br>  
Description with FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 LastName2, FirstName3 LastName3<br>

2. FirstName3 LastName3, FirstName4 LastName4<br>  
Description with FirstName3 and FirstName4 LastName4.<br>

3. FirstName3 LastName3, FirstName6 LastName6<br>  
Description with FirstName3 and FirstName6.<br>
```

Still only want to change the lines beginning with number/period/space and ending with line break.

```
1. [[FirstName1 LastName1]], [[FirstName2 LastName2]], [[FirstName3 LastName3]]<br>  
Description with FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 LastName2, FirstName3 LastName3<br>  

2. [[FirstName3 LastName3]], [[FirstName4 LastName4]]<br>  
Description with FirstName3 and FirstName4 LastName4.<br>  

3. [[FirstName3 LastName3]], [[FirstName6 LastName6]]<br>  
Description with FirstName3 and FirstName6.<br>
```

Don't match the word "Description". It is only used as an example.

Comment: Are you planning to use python to perform the substitution? I mean, are you going to read the file line-by-line and perform the replacement? Because if so, there are at least few solutions that seem to fit already, Emma's being probably one of the best. We may need to have a good sample of the raw input data.

Comment: Yes, the substitution is being done in Python. The regex is being run over a string variable. "Latest update" in my original post has an example of the string variable's content. If I could get it to stop matching at the first <br> at the end of the line with \d\.\s, it would work perfectly for me.

Comment: Does each line in your file contain everything from the number to the second `<br>`? Or is the line beginning with `Description` a separate line?

Comment: The entire thing is a string inside a variable, not a file. I have scraped a website and got several paragraphs that I have assigned to a variable. I am now trying to place double square brackets around names that appear in specific places. @Emma's response gets close, with the names being placed in double brackets, but it also places double brackets everywhere there is a ", ". For now, I'm manually removing the ones I do not need.

Comment: Actually, @sal, you've given me a good idea. I will work on a way to read each element individually from the site scrape and format it accordingly. That may address a couple of other issues I am having. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, some expression similar to,

```
(?<=\.\s|,\s)([^,\r\n]+)\s*(?=<br>|,)
```

and a replacement of,

```
[[\1]]
```

might be an option too.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=\.\s|,\s)([^,\r\n]+)\s*(?=<br>|,)"
test_str = ("1. John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, etc.<br>\n"
    "12. John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, etc.<br>")
subst = "[[\\1]]"

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
1. [[John Smith1]], [[John Smith2]], [[John Smith3]], [[etc.]]<br>
12. [[John Smith1]], [[John Smith2]], [[John Smith3]], [[etc.]]<br>
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/s0fiDi/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/s0fiDi/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: This is close to what I need. Please see updates to post for clarification. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```py
import re

st = "1. John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, etc.<br>"

re.findall(r"(?:\d\. )?(.*?)(?:, |<br>)", st)
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual, there are couple of ways to do this, but doing it with just a regex replace is probably not going to be enough. Here two options from me:

### Regex + string manipulation

Expanding on your original regex, you can use this one to have a better capture and skip the first number/dot/space group:

```
import re
st = '1. John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, etc.<br>'
re1 = r"(\d\.\s)*(.+?)(?:, |(<br>)$)"
new_st = re.sub(re1, r"\1[[\2]], \3", st)
print(new_st)
```

which gives us a value of:

```
new_st = '1. [[John Smith1]], [[John Smith2]], [[John Smith3]], [[etc.]], <br>'
```

Notice the last comma at the end. We could remove that one with:

```
new_st = ''.join(new_st.rsplit(", ", 1))
```

which gives us:

```
'1. [[John Smith1]], [[John Smith2]], [[John Smith3]], [[etc.]]<br>'
```

so overall you'd have:

```
import re
st = '1. John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, etc.<br>'
re1 = r"(\d\.\s)*(.+?)(?:, |(<br>)$)"
new_st = re.sub(re1, r"\1[[\2]], \3", st)  # notice I do capture the first group
new_st = ''.join(new_st.rsplit(", ", 1))
```

### Extract the core, then use split/join

This also uses a regex, but only to extract the *core* of the string. Then use a combination of join/split to achieve the desired result:

```
import re
st = '1. John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, etc.<br>'
re2 = r"(\d+\.\s+)(.+)(<br>)$"
sections = re.findall(re3, st)

# just to make it clearer i'll split the sections
the_number, the_core, the_end = sections[0]

# rework the core
the_core = ']], [['.join(the_core.split(','))

# glue all the pieces together adding what's missing
new_st = the_number + '[[' + the_core + ']]' + the_end
```

which gives as result:

```
'1. [[John Smith1]], [[ John Smith2]], [[ John Smith3]], [[ etc.]]<br>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
(^\d\.\s*)?(\s*)(?:([^,]+)(?=, |<br>$))
```

Replace by

```
\1\2[[\3]]
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/FOGVA1/3/)

If the space after `,` is not always there, then you should replace the positive lookahead with  `(?=.\s*|<br>)`

Comment: Again, my fault for not clarifying. I should have stated that I want
```1. John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, John Smith4<br>```
```This is the reason why John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, and John Smith4 did what they did.<br>```

to become this:  
```1. [[John Smith1]], [[John Smith2]], [[John Smith3]], [[John Smith4]]<br>```
```This is the reason why John Smith1, John Smith2, John Smith3, and John Smith4 did what they did.<br>```